# Open GL: draw rectangles with borders?

Tags: opengl

[image]

Check the image I produced, but what I want to do is producing those rectangles with borders, and set the background colour to another. How can I do that?

```
glRectf(top_left_x, top_left_y, bottom_right_x, bottom_right_y)?




if loop==0:
            ratio = 0.10
            glBegin(GL_QUADS)
            while ratio <= 1.0:
                width = window_width/2
                height = window_height
                long_length = width * ratio
                short_length = height* (1.0 - ratio)
                top_left_x = (width - long_length) / 2.0
                top_left_y = (height - window_height * (1.0-ratio)) /2
                bottom_right_x = top_left_x + long_length
                bottom_right_y = top_left_y + short_length
                glColor(1.0,1.0,1.0,0.5)
                glVertex3f(top_left_x, top_left_y, 0.0)
                glVertex3f(top_left_x + long_length, top_left_y, 0.0)
                glVertex3f(bottom_right_x,bottom_right_y, 0.0)
                glVertex3f(bottom_right_x-long_length,bottom_right_y, 0.0)
                ratio += 0.05
            glEnd()
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can draw a rectangle not filled this way:

```
glBegin(GL_LINES);



glVertex2d(top_left_x, top_left_y);             
glVertex2d( top_right_x, top_right_y);              
glVertex2d( bottom_right_x,bottom_right_y);             
glVertex2d(bottom_left_x,bottom_left_y);
glVertex2d(top_left_x, top_left_y);                 
glEnd();
```

OpenGL use a state machine. So for changing the color just put :

```
glColor3f (R, G, B);
```

before your drawing primitives.

So, mixing it up, your step should be:

1. choose fill color
2. draw fill rect with glRectf
3. choose border color
4. draw unfilled rect with the code I posted

These steps repeated for each rectangle you are drawing of course.

Comment: I've changed as what your provided, but I got exactly same image. Any more problems?

Comment: @user469652: you haven't post any code. With that single line I can't tell you more.

Comment: @user469652: first of all put glColor before glBegin

Comment: @user469652: if putting glColor doesn't solve the problem check your coordinate values. I suggest you to start drawing a single rectangle and when you get it like you want, then try with the complete figure.

Comment: @user469652: or use GL_LINE_STRIP and remove the last glVertex call

Comment: Hey @Heisenbug,

I think you meant GL_LINE_STRIP instead of GL_LINES, but thanks for the code.